# How to Add an Elif Statement After Searching for a String in a CSV File

Tags: python, csv

Using the code from this post [Search for string in CSV Files using python and write the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765087/search-for-string-in-csv-files-using-python-and-write-the-results/32957793#32957793), how would I get the code to print 'not found' when the string isn't found in the database as currently I can get it to print it but it prints it 4 times when i only want it once. I discovered that it prints not found as many times as there are records in the csv file for instance if there are 5 records in the file it will print 'not found' 5 times.

```
 import csv

 search_for = ['OneTouch AT','LinkRunner AT','AirCheck']

 with open('in.csv') as inf, open('out.csv','w') as outf:
     reader = csv.reader(inf)
     writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
     for row in reader:
         if row[0] in search_for:
             print('Found: {}'.format(row))
             writer.writerow(row)
        if row[0] not in search_for:
            print ('not found')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only ever one match, you could use `break` to end the `for` loop early; you can then add a `else` block the *loop*; it'll only execute if you did *not* break out of the loop (e.g. when no match was ever found:

```
for row in reader:
    if row[0] in search_for:
        print('Found: {}'.format(row))
        writer.writerow(row)
        break
else:
    print ('not found')
```

To rephrase this: the `else:` block of the above `for` loop is *only* executed if all iterations of the loop executed completely and were not interrupted. It will not execute if `break` was executed.

Since `break` is only executed if you found a match, you'll have the one match written out and `'not found'` is *not* printed. If no matches were found, all iterations complete and `'not found'` *is* printed.

If there can be more than one match you can't use `break`, as that would end the search after the first match. Instead, use a flag variable; start it at `False`, and set it to `True` when you find a match. After the loop, test for that flag variable, if it is still set to `False` you know no matches were found:

```
found = False

for row in reader:
    if row[0] in search_for:
        print('Found: {}'.format(row))
        writer.writerow(row)
        found = True

if not found:
    print ('not found')
```